# Making a text based server with netcat or other programs?

Tags: networking, python, netcat

The idea I have is to make a netcat server, and when you connect to it, the server runs a python script with which the user can interact. So for example the script asks for a number, and it outputs that number to the power of 3.
How can you do that? How do you run a program and redirect the output to the connected user and make them able to interact with it in real time?

Pseudo output:

```
$ nc 192.168.1.13  
Input a number: 2  
8  
(end)
```

The script:

```
print(str(int(input("Input a number: "))**3))
```

Comment: If you involve Python might as well do the networking in Python too...?

Comment: @frostschutz can you give an example? not sure where to start, im a bit of a noob

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html  for an example of IPv4 echo server. Hint, you don't need client - you can just use `nc`. If you still cannot get the code working, post whatever code you've written so far ( even if it doesn't work )  and then we can discuss how to improve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:50011,fork EXEC:'/path/to/script',stderr,pty,echo=0
```

Notes:

- `50011` is the listening port, you can choose your own. Connect to it later, e.g. `nc 127.0.0.1 50011`.
- `fork` allows `socat` to serve to many clients (also simultaneously).
- Without `pty` it's normal to get `Input a number:` only after you actually provided input blindly.
- My tests indicate that if one terminates `socat` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then the port may stay in use for a while. If it's a problem, consider `reuseaddr` (i.e. `TCP-LISTEN:50011,fork,reuseaddr`).